# How does Node.js convert your code to events?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

When you first run your Node program, how/what is the first event supplied to the event loop? Is your program like a top-level callback that is being executed the entire time? (And I would assume this top-level callback is usually "server.listen()"?)

Comment: Impossible to answer. Depends on the event that is firstly triggered. Pribably Process.nextTick when used. And no, the code is just executed once.

Comment: `server.listen()` - only if you are developing a server. A script will probably have a different starting point.

Comment: @ghert85 - Perhaps you could explain exactly what you are trying to do - that might help us provide more useful answers. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @lix i think hes confused about how js is executed, looks like he has a java background

Comment: @Jonasw - yes - this is what I am trying to establish :)

Comment: Yep, coming from Java. I've been kind of thinking of Node in terms of a Task Queue of Runnables, which may be the problem. I'm confused about whether the event loop exists outside of the "main" script (or entry point) being ran, or if the event loop runs the "main" script itself

Comment: Let's say you run "node app.js". Does the Node platform + event loop start, and then it queues 'app.js' as an event to the event loop? Or is each instruction / line of code as individual events?

Comment: @ghert outside! You cannot influence the event loop. While java is compiled, js is parsed ( yeah i know its not that easy), so while everything the java code does is written by you, nodejs does many things in the background you cannot influence. One of them is the event loop.

Comment: @ghert so your js is executed once. Then it writes event handlers into a tree. So app.get("/",..) just writes the function ... into a specific memory location. Then the execution of the js stops completely. Now theres just the event loop in the background. When a user sends a request to the server, the event loop notices a request on port 80, and then jumps to function ... and executes it...

Comment: @Jonasw It's the same for Java. The JVM does many things in the background that you cannot influence.

Comment: @bergi im just doing some basic java at school... but i think task qeues are maintained by users code right? So thats what i wanted to point out

Comment: @ghert85, trust no one. If you're really interested - just read the source: https://github.com/nodejs/node

I'm quite intrigued by the question so I'm digging in this too :)

Answer (score 2):

> I'm confused about whether the event loop exists outside of the "main" script (or entry point) being ran, or if the event loop runs the "main" script itself

Both, actually. The event loop is the mechanism that wraps all execution of js code, and won't stop as long as there are events to be awaited.

> what is the first event supplied to the event loop?

It's the evaluation of the main script. (Or rather, the native node.js code that will eventually evaluate your main script is the thing that is put first on the V8 event loop).

> Is your program like a top-level callback that is being executed the entire time?

No, nothing is executed the entire time, every callback is executed on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is just based on some missunderstanding. So lets start with the bascis:

*I've been kind of thinking of Node in terms of a Task Queue of Runnables, which may be the problem.*

Yes. NodeJS has nothing todo with a task qeue that is filled by the code you supply. The qeue is filled up by requests/timers and other stuff. Your code just provides methods, to handle such tasks.

*I'm confused about whether the event loop exists outside of the "main" script (or entry point) being ran, or if the event loop runs the "main" script itself*

The first one. The js is parsed first, when the code exits, the event loop starts.

```
//parse + execute the js
while(true){}
//this code never enters the event loop as the global scope js is blocking
```

*how/what is the first event supplied to the event loop?*

We dont know. It may be a timer, a user request, a file ready, etc.

Lets have a look at an example code:

```
//on start this js is parsed, qeue, heap and the global object are constructed
//a function is stored on the global object
function log(){
 console.log("Hi, im logged");
}

//the function pointer of log is pushed to the qeue
process.nextTick(log);

 //a hardware timer is initialised
setTimeout(log,1000);
//the parser ends, nodejs enters the event loop
```

At first, the js is parsed. After that, our global object contains a function log, and our Task qeue looks like this:

```
qeue=[ log ] //was added trough process.nextTick
```

In the background, theres a hardware timer running, that will finish somewhen.

Now the JS engine enters the event loop. The event loop processes the qeue. So it looks like sth like this (pseudocode):

```
while(true){    
  execute(qeue.shift())
}
```

So our log is called the first time, then our qeue is empty and the event loop will stop/ do some background tasks.

After one second, the timer finishes and pushes log onto the qeue:

```
function timer_finishes(){
  qeue.push(log);
}
```

So now our qeue contains another function to execute.

Normally the qeue is full of finished timers to execute, requests to answer and file read/write successes to handle.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks! I was thinking that it just blocks on something like "server.listen()" in the main script, and that Node terminated after reaching the end of the script.

Comment: @Danila Shutov thats a question of definition. If nodejs uses libuv to shedule an event loop, i think one can say that nodejs has an event loop.

Comment: @ghert85 no server.listen() just sets up the server and exits. The eventloop will then catch requests to the port specified and call the callbacks...